# Can I use Mutators in Query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-query-builder, mutators

I have created a mutator in my model.

```
Class Client {
   protected $fillable = ['name', 'age']

   public function getIndustryAttribute() {
      // some evaluations;

      return "Programmer"
   }
}
```

Now, I am trying to use `Client::where('industry', "Programmer")->get()` to get the value. Is this possible at all?

*Please bear in mind this is a totally pseudo code for explaining easier. I ended up this way because of mis-planning..*

Comment: You can't use Laravel's mutators for this as pointed out by @gbalduzzi's answer, they are evaluated after the query on the `Model` objects that are returned. There is however, a way you *could* achieve this, depending on your database platform. MySQL offers something called [Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) that could be a solution for you. I can't speak for any of the other supported databases though. Of course, it all depends on what kind of logic you need though, it might not be feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

Mutators are evaluated **after** the query has been executed.

What you can do when querying is to define the correct [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes).

It is not possible because applying a mutator when querying would be really performance heavy: it would be equivalent to looping through the whole table and performing the elaboration on every row.